# Out of Memory al leer un archivo excel con ClosedXML

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc

Tengo una interfaz en web, con MVC, c# y js, al momento de adjuntar el archivo al input se queda cargando y luego de un tiempo me da el menssage outofmemory.

El archivo se lee, se guarda en un datatable para despues insertarlo en bd.
Existe algún método o como puedo hacerle para evitar este saturamiento.
Adjunto el ejemplo del codigo
Estoy usand **ClosedXML**.

```
 using ( XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(path))
            {
                //var workBook = new XLWorkbook(path);
                //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
                IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet("Customer View");


                //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
                bool firstRow = true;
                foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
                {
                    //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                    if (firstRow)
                    {
                        foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                        }
                        firstRow = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Add rows to DataTable.
                        dt.Rows.Add();
                        int i = 0;

                        foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(row.FirstCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber, row.LastCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber))
                        {
                            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                workSheet = null;
            }
// INSERTO A SQL
 try
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertSQLby") { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@myTableType", dt));
                    cmd.Connection = conexion;
                    conexion.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conexion.Close();

                }
            }
```

El Excel tiene 114 registros y al rededor de 30 columnas, igual me gustaria leer solo algunas columnas y no todas, alguien tiene la idea de como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: amigo el catch de ese try que te manda?

Comment: Entiendo estas usando Table-Valued Parameters, no? Intentaste enviando un excel con menos registros para ver como responde? o quizas validar el procedure que opeaciones realiza con la estructura que envias por parametro?

Comment: Nisiquiera llega al SP, el error lo marca cuando esta cargando el archivo del path en la linea
using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(path))

este es el error:
OutOfMEmoryException was unhandled by user code
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.